# Build an restful api backend with node.js - problem how and where to start

Tags: node.js, express

I got an assignment to make a backend for the website with a Node.js framework of my choice to build a RESTful API of which the endpoints match the below specifications: 
-pagination in batches of 30
-get 5 movies
-Add a filter to the above, which will allow the api to return either male or female characters.
- Make sure all the characters can be sorted by height in ascending and
descending order.

I had no knowledge of node.js (isn't it weird assignment for a front end position?) so what I did is: I googled a little and watched some tutorials: built an api in express and fetched and displayed/filtered data in React (only solutions I knew how to did it). But now I'd like to do it again but onlly backend. My problem is I got no idea how and where to start. Should I learn about databases and do it with databases? If Sb can help me and give me hints where to start and what steps I should take!
Thanks!

Comment: Start with here-https://expressjs.com/en/starter/generator.html

Answer (score 0):

I created a simple CLI to help me to create project `nac new my-project --javascript` and generate files (Model / Controller / Service / Route ) for node.js / MongoDB project's `nac generate model user --javascript`

You can find the full documentation here and how to install the CLI : [node-cli](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@soubai/node-cli)

NB : you need to lean javascript/node.js first